react-table: Getting rendered value of column
I need to get an array of all rendered values of a column in order to populate an autocomplete component.
My problem is that the rendered values for the column in question are derived via a cell function, i.e.
cell: (context) => getCustomerValue(context.row.original.customerId)
Given a Table instance and column ID, is there a way of getting all rendered values of a column?
Many thanks!
